# Need help debugging kafka source to hdfs sink with flume

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

I'm trying to send data from kafka (eventually we'll use kafka running on a different instance) to hdfs. I think flume or some sort of ingestion protocol is necessary to get data into hdfs. So we're using cloudera's flume service and hdfs.

This is my flume-conf file. The other conf file is empty

```
tier1.sources=source1
tier1.channels=channel1
tier1.sinks=sink1

tier1.sources.source1.type=org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
tier1.sources.source1.zookeeperConnect=localhost:2181
tier1.sources.source1.topic=test
tier1.sources.source1.groupId=flume
tier1.sources.source1.channels=channel1
tier1.sources.source1.interceptors=i1
tier1.sources.source1.interceptors.i1.type=timestamp
tier1.sources.source1.kafka.consumer.timeout.ms=100

tier1.channels.channel1.type=memory
tier1.channels.channel1.capacity=10000
tier1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity=1000

tier1.sinks.sink1.type=hdfs
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path=/tmp/kafka/test/data
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval=5
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize=0
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollCount=0
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
```

When I start a kafka consumer it can get messages from a kafka producer just fine on localhost:2181. But I don't see any errors from the flume agent and nothing gets put into hdfs. I also can't find any log files.

This is how I start the agent.

```
flume-ng agent --conf /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/flume-ng/conf --conf-file flume-conf --name agent1 -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,INFO,console
```

Help please?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

Have to change
--name agent1
to --name tier1